# java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unmatched closing ')' : during string.split operation

Tags: java, regex, split

I am trying to perform a split similar the following:

```
String str = "({Somestring 1 with a lot of braces and commas}),({Somestring 12with a lot of braces and commas})";
println str.split("}),({");
```

But i see:

> java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unmatched closing ')' near index 0
>   }),({

Clearly , my string is being treated as a regular expression.

Is there a way i can escape this string?

Comment: Use: `str.split("}\\),\\({")`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

the character `(` and `)` and `{` and `}` are special character in regexp. you have to escape these:

```
println str.split("\\}\\),\\(\\{");
```

Answer (score 5):

Instead of escaping the string manually you can also treat it like a literal as opposed to a regex with:

```
println str.split(Pattern.quote("}),({"));
```

Answer (score 2):

`Java characters` that have to be `escaped` in `regular expressions` are:

> .[]{}()*+-?^$|

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "({Somestring 1 with a lot of braces and commas}),({Somestring 12with a lot of braces and commas})";
        String[] array = str.split("\\}\\),\\(\\{");
        System.out.println(array.length);
    }
```

Comment: Actually, {} does not need to be escaped in regex.